# Hide title not working in joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

Ok all I want is hide the article title, no big deal, right?

So here is what I have:
[image: my article title]

Here are my settings in the article manager - i disabled pretty much everthing, and yes, i cleared cache:

[image: my settings in article manager]

Guess what, the title does not disappear. I am getting really tired of this bad quality.
I had the same problems with the tags, they wouldn't disappear. But you can just remove all tags you have in an article to make em disappear (great solution right)

Is it joomla or is it me?

[I read a weird comment about having to disable author to disable the title here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/article-options/show-title)

> During our testing, simply setting Show Title will not hide the title. You also need to set the option Show Author to hide as well.

That was in version 3.0

**EDIT**
I was debugging, and I saw this as implementation of `C:\xampp\apps\joomla\htdocs\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php`:

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_title') || $params->get('show_author')) : ?>
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>
        <?php if ($this->item->state == 0) : ?>
            <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && !empty($this->item->readmore_link)) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>"> <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?></a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </h2>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So a div and h2 is rendered in case author is available, should be empty when title is hidden though.

Show title is always 1, whatever I do, link_titles btw as well. The only way to disable it is going to the global configuration and setting the global configuration to Hide, whatever I am doing in the Article Manager Options tab of an article seems to have no effect (setting it to Hide, Show, Global). It seems to be fixed on 'Global'. At least with what I tested with

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. Even changes in global can't help me in 3.2.0. Only patching components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php was hepful.

Comment: @E-Hauler try the menu item manager.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What I found is this (Joomla 3.2):
In Menu Manager -> Edit Menu Item -> Options
Set Show Title to Use Article Settings

In Article Manager - Edit Article -> Options
Set Show Title to Hide.

Worked for me.
Gert

[image: -- See attached screen shot for the option to change in 3.2.3 --]

Comment: Also, you should hide Name field in the contact manager -> section "Display"

Answer (score 9):

You can 'control' the display of 'article titles' in three places

1 - Article Manager then 'options' button (top right). This will modify every article in your site, basically changes the default.

2 - Individual article, 'options' tab (center of page just above the editor). This will modify setting for this specific article AND it "overrides" the global article option setting.

3 - Menu item, 'options' tab (center of page just above the editor).This "overrides" the global article option settings and the article option setting.

Comment: it seemed to me that 2. has no effect at all.

Comment: I think it finally was the menu item setting that did the trick. So even if I disagree with your answer, (2 plain ineffective) for me the solution was using menu item manager

Comment: There's also in the menu item "page display" -> "show page heading", which doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 6):

I have just visited your question and the answers given.
If you just want to hide the titles of the articles you have assigned to the menu items in joomla 3.2, you do not need to hide them globally.

Instead there is a tab named **Advanced Options** in

```
Menu Manager: Edit Menu Item.
```

In which you will find

```
Article options => Show Title => Hide
```

By this way you can easily hide the title of the article which are linked to that menu item's link.

I wish this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Joomla 3.3, and to make the títle "Home" dissapear on first page, I found the solution here by toskan:
Go to Menu Manager, edit menu Home, and on tab "Page Display" remove "Show Page Heading"

Answer (score 1):

Why is it like this? So you can have the flexibility to change your display but also the simplicity to set your most commonly used settings in global configuration.

Global configuration sets the default display.  You should set your globals to the most common settings that you will use in your site. Then you should only use individual article or menu settings when you want to override those settings.  Really, most people never need to override becasue they want to have a consistent look and feel.

However, if you do want to have a mixture of settings the next step is to change individual items. For example on a given article you may have a date show even though by default you never show a date.

Still, what if sometimes you want to show the author but sometimes you don't? Do you have to copy the article completely to set new params? No, that would be ridiculous and a pain to maintain. In that case you create a menu item linking to that article. The menu link options can be used to override the options from the specific article. Again, you should really only be using this in special cases since you have already thoughtfully set your global and item level settings.

So the cascade is  menu overrides item overrides global.

Joomla also gives you a lot of other options for this kind of thing such as you can even put  an alternate layout. It could be (and is) a criticism that joomla goes too far in letting you customize everything so much and it creates an overwhelming UI, but on the other hand if you are used to it, it is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

hide website Title :

*extension* >> *template Manager*

*Protostart*

go to *Options* and tape a SPACE in *TITLE*

that will delete your Title and replace it by a space...TRICK that cant harm..

working 100%

maybe same for module or article title..

Comment: This is correct - I have like many other on here been tearing my hair out because it was displaying the domain name at the top. Inserting a space works and doesn't keep the height attribute. I am liking Joomla so far but this bit has given me a big headache. Thanks Pierree.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to The Menu Item, then click on the tab "Link Type" it will ask "Add meny title:" set that to NO.

This worked for me.

edit: Check also the "Page Display" Tab

Answer (score 1):

I may have found another solution. I am working on Joomla 2.5 though but maybe 3.2 may have similar settings. Took a bit to find but here goes. This applies if the Article has been associated as a menu item:

- Go to Menu Manager then click the culprit menu item.
- Then scroll down to "Page Display Options"

I would have attached an image for clarity, but alas I need 10 reputation.

For some reason though, this overrides the rules for Global Config and Article config to hide the article headings.

I hope this helps someone.

**Update :**

In Joomla 3.2 you can find this under the Page Display in the Menu Manager once you click into the Menu Item. By default headings are visible

Answer (score 1):

**Solution is simple.**

If article is also a menu item you have to set it in **settings for menu item**, otherwise it wont work!

Comment: Thank you, it was my first post and i really believed it is the right answer.  I believe that "About me" article in question is also set as menu item. Question was about why he is not able to hide title. He was trying to debug code, change global settings, but in my opinion answer is that he can do that but from the level of menu item settings, not article itself.

Im sorry if that is not an answer, but i was searching web with this problem and found this thread. I found the solution so i have posted it here.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't understand, but the title is coming from the Menu Item. So there is the article title which you can show / hide / throw into the streets / dowhatever and nothing happens. Then there is the 'Global Configuration' for the articles, when I set the title to 'Hide' there, it will hide the actual thing , but yeah, for all articles.
Then there is the Menu Item manager which imho has no importance for the title displayed in the content. But okay, if you globally enable the article titles and then disable the menu item title for this menu item, it will actually hide the article title. You can still do whatever you want in the article options of the single article.
Probably the same accounts for show hiding tags of the ARTICLE.

It is good I don't have a gun in my place, I would probably have blasted my brains onto the next wall. Time spent for this crap: over 1 hour.

If someone can reasonably explain why it is like that, I will certainly accept or upvote.